# Terraform Locals Produces Multiple counts of Resource Group

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have some Azure Terraform code for a complex map(object) variable for a azuerm_data_collection_rule as part of Azure Monitor. Inside that variable, are many list(objects) that represent possible dynamic blocks a user may or may not enter into a tfvars definition. For example, there is a destinations block and inside that block is a list of possible destinations, including Log Analytics.

When creating the tfvars inputs, a user may in fact enter the same destination for each data collection rule. So, they may create 2 or more rules, each with the same destination Log Analytics Workspace.

The resource creation azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule calls for the id of said Log Analytics workspace. So, I was looking to use a data lookup on it since we do not want the users directly putting a ResourceID into the tfvars. Therefore, we provide for the user to enter the name and resource group of the workspace and we then use a data source to look it up.

So, we have a variable, a locals that attempts to transform that and the data source. My construct is wrong somewhere because in my outputs I am still getting duplicate resource groups like this, when I am looking for one.

**outputs**

```
unique_log_analytics = {
  "law-eus2-dc" = [
    "rg-eus2-law",
    "rg-eus2-law",
  ]
```

I have tried a few attempts here to correct this, but cannot clean it up. It does plan out and apply correctly in the current config though.

```
### Data Collection Rule
variable "data_collection_rules" {
  type = map(object({
    data_collection_endpoint_id = optional(string)
    data_flow = list(object({
      built_in_transform = optional(string)
      destinations       = list(string)
      output_stream      = optional(string)
      streams            = list(string)
      transform_kql      = optional(string)
    }))
    data_sources = optional(list(object({
      data_import = optional(list(object({
        event_hub_data_source = list(object({
          consumer_group = optional(string)
          name           = string
          stream         = string
        }))
      })))
      extension = optional(list(object({
        extension_json     = optional(string)
        extension_name     = string
        input_data_sources = optional(list(string))
        name               = string
        streams            = list(string)
      })))
      iis_log = optional(list(object({
        log_directories = optional(list(string))
        name            = string
        streams         = list(string)
      })))
      log_file = optional(list(object({
        file_patterns = list(string)
        format        = string
        name          = string
        settings = optional(list(object({
          text = list(object({
            record_start_timestamp_format = string
          }))
        })))
        streams = list(string)
      })))
      performance_counter = optional(list(object({
        counter_specifiers            = list(string)
        name                          = string
        sampling_frequency_in_seconds = number
        streams                       = list(string)
      })))
      platform_telemetry = optional(list(object({
        name    = string
        streams = list(string)
      })))
      prometheus_forwarder = optional(list(object({
        label_include_filter = optional(set(object({
          label = string
          value = string
        })))
        name    = string
        streams = list(string)
      })))
      syslog = optional(list(object({
        facility_names = list(string)
        log_levels     = list(string)
        name           = string
        streams        = optional(list(string))
      })))
      windows_event_log = optional(list(object({
        name           = string
        streams        = list(string)
        x_path_queries = list(string)
      })))
      windows_firewall_log = optional(list(object({
        name    = string
        streams = list(string)
      })))
    })))
    description = optional(string)
    destinations = list(object({
      azure_monitor_metrics = optional(list(object({
        name = string
      })))
      event_hub = optional(list(object({
        namespace_name      = string
        resource_group_name = string
        name                = string
      })))
      log_analytics = optional(list(object({
        workspace_name      = string
        resource_group_name = string
      })))
      storage_blob = optional(list(object({
        storage_account_name   = string
        storage_container_name = string
        resource_group_name    = string
      })))
    }))
    identity = optional(list(object({
      identity_ids = optional(set(string))
      type         = string
    })))
    kind = optional(string)
    stream_declaration = optional(set(object({
      column = list(object({
        name = string
        type = string
      }))
      stream_name = string
    })))
    tags = optional(map(string))
  }))
  default = {}
}
```

**Locals**

```
locals {
  log_analytics = flatten([
    for rule in var.data_collection_rules : [
      for dest in rule.destinations : [
        for law in try(dest.log_analytics, []) : {
          workspace_name      = law.workspace_name
          resource_group_name = law.resource_group_name
        }
      ]
    ]
  ])

  // Creating a map with a unique workspace_name to resource_group_name
  unique_log_analytics = {
    for law in local.log_analytics : law.workspace_name => law.resource_group_name...
  }
}
```

**Data**

```
data "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "this" {
  for_each            = local.unique_log_analytics
  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = each.value[0]
}
```

**Snippet of Main.tf**

```
  # Destinations
  dynamic "destinations" {
    for_each = tolist(coalesce(each.value.destinations, []))
    iterator = dest
    content {
      # Azure Monitor Metrics
      # Event Hub
      # Event Hub Direct

      # Log Analytics
      dynamic "log_analytics" {
        for_each = tolist(coalesce(dest.value.log_analytics, []))
        iterator = la
        content {
          workspace_resource_id = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.this[la.value.workspace_name].id
          name                  = la.value.workspace_name
        }

      }

      # Monitor Account left out because we don't know what it refers to

      # Storage Blob

      # Storage Blob Direct left out for now

      # Storage Table Direct left out for now
    }
  }
```

**TFVars Input Snippet** - for each data collection rule, a user could input this exact same destination.

```
    destinations = [{
      log_analytics = [{
        workspace_name      = "law-eus2-dc"
        resource_group_name = "rg-eus2-law"
      }]
    }]
```

**Current Error**

```
Changes to Outputs:
  ~ log_analytics_output = [
      - {
          - resource_group_name = "rg-eus2-law"
          - workspace_name      = "law-eus2-dc"
        },
      - {
          - resource_group_name = "rg-eus2-law"
          - workspace_name      = "law-eus2-dc"
        },
      + [
          + [
              + {
                  + resource_group_name = "rg-eus2-law"
                  + workspace_name      = "law-eus2-dc"
                },
            ],
        ],
    ]

You can apply this plan to save these new output values to the Terraform state, without changing any real infrastructure.
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on locals.tf line 14, in locals:
│   14:     for law in local.log_analytics : law.workspace_name =>
│ 
│ This value does not have any attributes.
```

Answer (score 1):

My keen observation was on how you use a nested loop to iterate over the `var.data_collection_rules` and destinations, which can lead to duplicates and also, how you construct the `unique_log_analytics` local variable, that meant for mapping from `workspace_name` to `resource_group_name`.

Therefore, I will advise that instead of the above, you can use the ***toset*** function in Terraform to remove duplicates when creating a unique mapping.

Then, you might need to consider using the correct structure, when constructing the `unique_log_analytics` map.

However, you can see a sample of your code on how to use ***toset*** for uniqueness in the `log_analytics` set:

```
locals {
  log_analytics = toset([
    for rule in var.data_collection_rules : [
      for dest in rule.destinations : [
        for law in try(dest.log_analytics, []) : {
          workspace_name      = law.workspace_name
          resource_group_name = law.resource_group_name
        }
      ]
    ]
  ])

  unique_log_analytics = {
    for law in local.log_analytics : law.workspace_name => 
law.resource_group_name
  }
}
```

The above code will directly map `workspace_name` to `resource_group_name`.

I hope this is helpful to resolves the issue of duplicates in your outputs. If you still encounter problems, please provide more details or share any error messages you receive.

Comment: thank you for that. I will try it out. I guess my follow-up question already is why do I need the unique_log_analytics anyway? Is there a way to construct the first locals so that it always produces a unique output on its own?

Comment: I added that new output above. Throws an error.

Comment: 1. The unique_log_analytics local variable is created to have a unique mapping from workspace_name to resource_group_name. It is highly useful even for future configurations, you will be rest asure of no duplicates.

Comment: 2.  Yes, is to ensures that each combination of workspace_name and resource_group_name appears only once in the set. THAT WAS THE REASON BEHIND THE SAMPLE CODE.

Comment: 3. Output with error: If there is no specific error message, I might not be able to know what goes wrong. Confirm that the data structure matches your expectations and check the output to make sure it matches your expected format and also, verify that the error is coming from the specific block of code and not from somewhere else in your configuration.